# Apply animation inside DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have a listbox with the following structure. Data displays well and no issues there. I want to get some animation affect for the StackPanel, but since it is inside the DataTemplate, I am not able to use Blend to get my desired animation affect.

I guess I can write an event handler and code for that, but is that the best approach of achieving animation for ListBox items?

```
  <ListBox Height="600" ItemsSource="{StaticResource learn}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Height="100" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Width="0" Text="{Binding ID}" />
           <Image Height="100" Width="100"/>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="319" VerticalAlignment="Center">
              <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="6,0,0,0" FontSize="29.333" />
               <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="6,0,0,0" FontSize="16"/>
           </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all you need to do is to create a new user control and add all your animations to that user control and start animation where you want. In the list box data template, create an instance of that data template.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new User Control in the project.
2. Give in the animations to the animations to that user control in blend.
3. Add the user control in data template.
4. Start the animations where ever you want.

Alternative: Without creating a new user control you can specify animations by creating storyboard and applying required transformations. this gives a common animation to all the list box items.